# Put Md5 checksum to file name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

There some files in directory 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt .. n.txt , i need rename them all with their md5 sum. 
I tired

```
for %f in (*.txt) do certutil -hashfile "%f" MD5 | findstr /C:2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you **really need** to do it from command line (from the syntax in your question) you only need an additional `for /f` to process the output of the `certutil` command executed for each file.

```cmd
for %a in (*.txt) do @for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,* delims=:" %b in ('certutil -hashfile "%a" MD5') do @if "%c"=="" @echo ren "%a" "%b%~xa"
```

The `for /f` uses a `skip` clause to avoid the first line in the `certutil`'s ouput (the file name) and colon as a delimiter to split lines to handle the non needed output messages (that start with `CertUtil:`).

That way if the line contains a colon (non needed line), it will be splitted in two (`tokens=1,*`), storing the left token in `%b` and the right one in `%c`.

If `%c` has any content this is not the line containing the hash. If `%c` is empty, this is the line with the hash and we rename the file.

Notes:

- The `ren` command is only echoed to console. If the output seems right, remove the `echo` command.
- If a file can not be read (locked or empty) the `certutil` only outputs error lines, so there will not be any hash and all lines will be discarded not executing the rename operation.

Anyway, doing this from command line is prone to errors. If you can, as Hackoo suggests, use a batch file.

```cmd
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('
        cmd /q /c "for %%f in (*.txt) do certutil -hashfile "%%f" MD5&&(echo file:%%f)"
        ^| findstr /v /b /i /c:"MD5" /c:"Cert" 
    ') do (
        if "%%a"=="file" (
            set "file=%%b"
            set "extension=%%~xb"
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
                echo ren "!file!" "!md5: =!!extension!"
            endlocal
            set "md5="
        ) else (
            set "md5=%%a"
        )
    )
```

**edited** to include in batch code the correction pointed by sst in comments

Comment: Afrer batch run, script have changed name, but lost file extension. Like thaht "e2cfe4cd8e52eed3e602b6730df29d4e". No file extension

Comment: @AligamarliNamazov Did you at least test my batch ?

Comment: @AligamarliNamazov, Answer updated. You only need to change `ren "%a" %b` into `ren "%a" "%b%~xa"` (to keep the extension from file being referenced by `%a`) or if you will only process `.txt` files then you can simply use `ren "%a" %b.txt`

Comment: @MCND, On some windows versions hash algorithm have to be passed in uppercase or cerutil will fail, This is definitely the case on my Windows 7, certutil on my Windows 10 accepts lower, upper and mixed cases. I couldn't find any official statement from Microsoft regarding this behavior. Also removing spaces from the hash string seems to be a good idea, Again because of different output format between Windows versions. e.g. `e2 cf e4 cd ...` vs `e2cfe4cd...`

Comment: @sst, Thanks, you are right. Bad memory and having only windows 10 at hand end this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this batch script, just save it as **Rename2MD5.bat** and put it in the same directory where your text files are stored and execute it by double click
And if all is OK, you can remove the `echo` command before the `Ren` command.

```dos
@echo off
Color 0A 
Title Rename Files to MD5 Hashes
echo(
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
     for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%H in ('CertUtil -hashfile "%%a" MD5 ^| findstr /i /v "CertUtil"') do ( set H=%%H)
        echo "%%a" = "!H!.txt"
        echo Ren "%%a" "!H!.txt"
)
EndLocal
Pause & Exit
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure that my newly renamed `.txt` files are not cycled back into the initial `For` loop, and because the result of the MD5 will probably be a set of two character strings separated by spaces, I'd probably consider doing it a little more like this with a batch file:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('Set _[ 2^>Nul') Do Set "%%A="

For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=]" %%A In ('Where .:*.txt 2^>Nul^|Find /N /V ""') Do (
    For /F "Delims=" %%C In ('CertUtil -HashFile "%%B" MD5 2^>Nul^|Find /V ":"'
    ) Do (Set "_=%%C" & Call Set "_%%A]=Ren "%%B" "%%_: =%%%%~xB""))

For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A In ('Set _[ 2^>Nul') Do %%B
```